# How to set filterset(django-filter) for custom action of viewset?

Tags: django-rest-framework

How i can do it? I find only this example, but it isn't what i need

```
import django_filters

class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'price', 'manufacturer']

def product_list(request):
    filter = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.all())
    return render(request, 'my_app/template.html', {'filter': filter})
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can override the get_filterset_class method and return filter set class based on self.action .

Comment: Can you please elaborate steps how to do and provide example?